# LED on keyboard don't light on Thinkapd t480s

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad

Does anybody have an idea why mute and microphone LEDs on my Lenovo Thinkpad t480s do not light in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS?

Tips are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work on kernel 4.13.0-37-generic ; but after an mainline kernel upgrade to kernel version 4.15.15 it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in the terminal

```
acpi_listen
```

Now press the button mute button.
Then give use the results likely something like this:

```
ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 0000101b
```

Then open up nano or another text editor.

> nano /etc/acpi/events/lenovo-mutemic

And adjust the following for your hotkey.

```
event=ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 0000101b
action=/etc/acpi/lenovo-mutemic.sh
```

Then we need to make a shells script.

```
  #!/bin/bash
INPUT_DEVICE="'Internal Mic'"
YOUR_USERNAME="place_your_username_here"
if amixer sget $INPUT_DEVICE,0 | grep '\[on\]' ; then
    amixer sset $INPUT_DEVICE,0 toggle
    echo "0 blink" > /proc/acpi/ibm/led
    su $YOUR_USERNAME -c 'DISPLAY=":0.0" notify-send -t 50 \
            -i microphone-sensitivity-muted-symbolic "Mic MUTED"'
else
    amixer sset $INPUT_DEVICE,0 toggle                       
    su $YOUR_USERNAME -c 'DISPLAY=":0.0" notify-send -t 50 \
            -i microphone-sensitivity-high-symbolic "Mic ON"'
    echo "0 on" > /proc/acpi/ibm/led 
fi
```

Now let's just make it excutable and restart the service.

> sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/lenovo-mutemic.sh
>
> sudo service acpid restart

There are some other methods but this would likely fix the issue.